# SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Case.Account

Tags: apex, visualforce

My SOQL

```
SELECT id, Account.Name from Case
```

And 
using it in VF

```
<apex:outputText value="{!C.Account.Name}"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: and the rest of your code along with the line that is causing the error?

Comment: The answer below is proof that we have no idea until we see a bit more detail around the location of the error and your code

Comment: @Eric- My code is same as the one posted below. It's working fine in case of other fields . Only when I add Account.Name in both controller and Vf that I am getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working example:

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="TestCtrl">
    <apex:repeat value="{!Cases}" var="C">
        <apex:outputText value="{!C.Account.Name}"/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class TestCtrl {
    public List<Case> getCases() {
        return [SELECT id, Account.Name from Case];
    }
}
```

Comment: My code is exactly the same . And I am getting error , once I am adding the Account.Name field to the VF and Controller.

Comment: Just copy and paste my example. Checked it and it works fine.